# How to skip email notification for at command in AIX?

Tags: email, aix, scheduling, at

(AIX 6.1 ) `man` page for `at` says `-m` option could send an email to the user. But this is the default behavior, even without specifying the -m option. Is there a way to turn this off, I do not want mails sent to the user account. `man` page has no information. I tried `+m` but it is not accepted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty simple and also explained in the [man page of the `at` command](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/at.htm)

> The at command **mails you all output from standard output and standard
>   error for the scheduled commands, *unless you redirect that output***.
>   It also writes the job number and the scheduled time to standard
>   error.

Same as for cron, simply redirect stdout and stderr to some file or to /dev/null if you don't need the output, but then you should be pretty sure what job you're running and how to check the results. Simple example would be something like the following (or whatever at job you want to run) :

```
echo "errlogger 'at test' &> /dev/null" | at now today
```

If that does not work with the shell you select, try the classic way

```
echo "errlogger 'at test' >/dev/null 2>&1" | at now today
```

Maybe it could be worth a try, testing if the same trick as for cron works for `at`. That is, try prefixing the at job with `MAILTO=""`